# How can I always replace a certain path parameter to another value in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My code example:

```
router.get('/name/:name/height', (req,res) => {
    ...
}

router.get('/name/:name/weight', (req,res) => {
    ...
}

router.get('/age/:age/height', (req,res) => {
    ...
}

router.get('/age/:age/weight', (req,res) => {
    ...
}
```

Here, when `name` comes as `foo`, I want to replace it to `bar` because `foo` is an alias of `bar`.

But inserting if-replace codes into all the blocks repeatedly doesn't look good.

Is there any other option to implement this??

---

I tried with:

```
router.use('/name/:name', (req, res, next) => {
    let name = req.params.name
    if (name === 'foo') {
        console.log("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH")
        req.params.name = 'bar'
    }
    next()
    }
)
```

That `HHH...` log is printed, but the req.params.name doesn't seem to be updated.

Comment: You can wrap these if-replace codes into a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html), then put that middleware in any router you need.

Comment: @namgold I tried to use `router.use`. Could you please find the problem from the updated code?

Comment: I wrote them in an answer.

Comment: Take a look on the router.param function/middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` is indeed an alias for `bar`, I'd suggest you respond with a `301 Redirect` response for the `foo` endpoint with something like this:

```
router.get('/name/foo/:path', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, '/name/bar/' + req.path);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap these if-replace codes into a middleware `myCustomMiddleware` then put that middleware in any router you need:

```js
const myCustomMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    let name = req.params.name;
    if (name === 'foo') {
        req.params.name = 'bar';
    }
    next();
};

router.get('/name/:name/height', myCustomMiddleware, (req,res) => {
    ...
});

router.get('/name/:name/weight', myCustomMiddleware, (req,res) => {
    ...
});

router.get('/age/:age/height', (req,res) => {
    ...
});

router.get('/age/:age/weight', (req,res) => {
    ...
});
```

Try on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@namgold/GracefulPriceyApplescript)

Comment: Thanks Namgold, but isn't there a way to achieve this without changing the existing code? I expected that my above code would change the req.params and go next(), but it didn't.

Comment: It didn't work.. https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2911 seems to say it's hard to modify req.params. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I think it's because you use `router.use` to set `req.params`, then `router.get...` reset it, so that way will not work.